# Offsite backup software?

Tags: backup, software-rec, proxmox

I have rented dedicated proxmox based server in a datacenter and I want to make offsite backups for it, because I don't want to loose any data and this server doesn't have RAID configuration. Is there any software that allows you to transfer whole server data along virtual machines to different location (Preferably daily without my intervention to cloud drive or to my personal PC. I would like to do that as cheap as possible)? I don't have GUI and I don't plan to install it. I will be glad if somebody has any idea how to do that.

Comment: Did you do a basic search for backup software? There is `restic` and `borgbackup` that do deduplicated backups, for example. What are your requirements?

Comment: is the pve server using zfs for storage? Then it would be just a matter of using `zfs send`.

Comment: My requirement is to backup whole physical server along with it's virtual machines to different device - Can by my personal PC, cloud based storage or NAS.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest giving [restic](https://github.com/restic/restic) a shot. It's very easy to use and quite powerful. If you want to learn about it, I wrote a blog post series on `restic`, giving a brief introduction, examples on how to use, examples on how to install and some real life usage scenarios.

https://remo-hoeppli.medium.com/restic-backup-i-simple-and-beautiful-backups-bdbbc178669d